# Login with Facebook, How to generate a password?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I let users to log into my website using 2 methods :

- old school method (username, password and email inputs)
- using their Facebook account.

I wrote this below function which I think can handle both of these 2 methods :

```
function register(type, username, password, email){
    // 1. ajax 
    // 2. reload page
}
```

With old school method, I do

```
$("#register").click(function(){

    register("old_school", username.val(), password.val(), email.val());

});
```

With Facebook, I do

```
$("#with-facebook").click(function(){

    FB.login(function(response) {

        if (response.status === 'connected') {

            FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                register("facebook", response.name, response.id, response.email);

            });
        }

    }, {scope:'public_profile,email'});
});
```

The problem is Facebook ids are not private. So I can't use it as a password.

**My question** : which one of Facebook fields I can use as users initial password ?

Comment: You don't need to save password if user registers with FACEBOOK. Just leave `password` field as `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a wordpress plugin that does the same: allow me to create user either with *old_school* method or with *facebook connect* method.

So, I suggest: maintain a private entry in your system which will be used for facebook-connected users. In my plugin,I follow this process:

```
// We want to ensure that no facebook-connected user
// knows his/her password so every time someone login via facebook-connect,
// we just update the "password for all"
$CONFIG['oauth_password'] = rand();

// Update user with this new password, as if he/she is updating his/her password
updateUserPassword($user.name,$CONFIG['oauth_password']);

// Now use this password as the user's password and do the actual login. We are sure that the user does not his/her password and will not know also
doLogin($user.name, $CONFIG['oauth_password'], $other data);
```